# WCF and Entity framework 4.1 POCO

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4.1

`I have the below entity framework 4.1 model.

```
public partial class AWLTR2Model : DbContext
{
    public AWLTR2Model()
        : base("name=AWLTR2Model")
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

I have the below POCO entity which is in different name space AWLTR2.Entity

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
public partial class CustomerAddress
{

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string AddressType { get; set; }
    public System.Guid rowguid { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

I exposed these entities through WCF services (BasicHTTPBinding) , but in my client , i am unable to add the child entities to the parent entity like below.

```
  Customer c = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = "xx",
            CompanyName = "zz",
            EmailAddress = "xx@a.com",
            LastName = "yy",
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
            NameStyle = false,
            PasswordHash = "abcd",
            PasswordSalt = "abcd",
            Phone = "xx",
            rowguid = System.Guid.NewGuid()
        };

        CustomerAddress ca = new CustomerAddress 
        { 
            AddressID = 9 , 
            Customer = c , 
            AddressType ="Home Office", 
            ModifiedDate=System.DateTime.Now, 
            rowguid = System.Guid.NewGuid()
        };
```

The add method is missing in the client , but i am able to do this without exposing WCF.
as like below. 
           c.CustomerAddresses.Add(ca);

I want to write a method to add customer along with address and customeraddress at one shot.  I acheived the same using entity framewor 4.0 with object context. but could not able to do so in Dbcontext.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

If `Add` method doesn't exist on the client it most probably means that you have added Service Reference to your WCF service but you didn't change default type for collection - default is array.

Configure your service reference and in advanced settings change Collection type to List.